# Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives.eslint-plugin-vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
export default {
    data() {
        return {
          cities : [
            'Bangalore','Chennai','Cochin','Delhi','Kolkata','Mumbai'
        ],

        value: '',
            open: false,
            current: 0
        }
    },
    props: {
        suggestions: {
            type: Array,
            required: true
        },
        selection: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            twoWay: true
        }
    },
    computed: {
        matches() {
            return this.suggestions.filter((str) => {
                return str.indexOf(this.selection) >= 0;
            });
        },
        openSuggestion() {
            return this.selection !== "" &&
                   this.matches.length != 0 &&
                   this.open === true;
        }
    },
    methods: {
        enter() {
            this.selection = this.matches[this.current];
            this.open = false;
        },
        up() {
            if(this.current > 0)
                this.current--;
        },
        down() {
            if(this.current < this.matches.length - 1)
                this.current++;
        },
        isActive(index) {
            return index === this.current;
        },
        change() {
            if (this.open == false) {
                this.open = true;
                this.current = 0;
            }
        },
        suggestionClick(index) {
            this.selection = this.matches[index];
            this.open = false;
        },
    }
}
```

```html
<template>
<div style="position:relative" v-bind:class="{'open':openSuggestion}">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" v-model="selection"
        @keydown.enter = 'enter'
        @keydown.down = 'down'
        @keydown.up = 'up'
        @input = 'change'
    />
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="width:100%">
        <li 
            v-for="suggestion in matches"
            v-bind:class="{'active': isActive($index)}"
            @click="suggestionClick($index)"
        >
            <a href="#">{{ suggestion }}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</template>
```

Getting eslint error [vue/require-v-for-key] Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives.eslint-plugin-vue.

Tried changing to  v-bind:key="suggestion.id" after changing, eslint error is not showing but issue is Autocomplete is not displaying(completely not working).

Can any one correct me if anything is wrong in the code.

Comment: hows your data looks like for `suggestions` and `selection`?

Comment: @RiyazKhan, suggestions for filtering data and selection is for matching the content and checking

Comment: could you share the sample data as exactly matching with those 2 properties

Comment: chennai and cochin

Comment: return {
          cities : [..........]
}

Comment: bro, with that only we cannot understand. create sample like this: ['chennai', 'cochin'] or if array object [{ city: 'chennai', id: 2 }]

Comment: I have added to the scripting file above, can u please check, it's in question above

Comment: I check that, but I found error while compiling code, in your selection and suggestion props.

Comment: Ok can we pass this sample data,   users: [{
                id: 1,
                text: "Stainless Steel Round Bars",
                done: false
              },
              {
                id: 2,
                text: "Aluminum Round Bars",
                done: false
              },
              {
                id: 3,
                text: "Brass Round Bars",
                done: true
              },
              {
                id: 4,
                text: "Oil Hardened Drill Rods",
                done: true
              }
            ],

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-franklin-gs6jh?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/src/components/SearchAutocomplete.vue

Comment: Now its working But instead of storing the values in App.vue, Can we able to store it inside of Scrpting file Or template

Answer (score 2):

When using `v-for` Vue would like to have a hint on how to identify the items in your list. You don't have to do it, but it is considered best practice and therefore eslint marks it.

To give the hint you add a `key` attribute with a unique value (id, some text, whatever) to the rendered list item like this:

```
<li 
  v-for="suggestion in matches"
  v-bind:key="suggestion.id"
>
```

`v-bind:key` or `:key` in short. The value must be of type `number | string | boolean | symbol`.

See the docs for more info: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State

Comment: I tried changing the value as v-bind:key="suggestion.id", But issue is Autocomplete bar is not working

Answer (score 0):

As you already added the `v-bind:key`, Now in your code, I believe the issue is with `$index`, remove that and use the suggestions' index.

**Here is the updated code, replace your dropdown-menu and check:**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="width:100%">
        <li 
            v-for="(suggestion, index) in matches"
            v-bind:key="suggestion.id"
            v-bind:class="{'active': isActive(index)}"
            @click="suggestionClick(index)"
        >
            <a href="#">{{ suggestion }}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: I replaced but still same,  May be the error in js file?